# Traversing an adjacent list

Tags: php, algorithm, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a list of all users under a specified upline.
E.g. upline id 1 has a downline of (2,3,4,5,6)

My table looks like this.

```
+----------------------+-----+------+
| line_id | upline_id| downline_id| main_upline_id|
+----------------------+-----+------+
| 1       |  0       |   1        |   0  |
| 2       |  1       |   2        |   1  |
| 3       |  2       |   3        |   1  |
| 4       |  3       |   4        |   1  |
| 5       |  1       |   5        |   1  |
| 6       |  5       |   6        |   1  |
| 7       |  0       |   7        |   0  |
| 8       |  7       |   8        |   7  |
| 9       |  8       |   9        |   7  |
| 10      |  9       |   10       |   7  |
+----------------------+-----+------+
```

And my code

```
    public function downline($id, $array) {
        $lineModel      = CLONEAPI::getModel( 'line' );
        $data           = $lineModel->getAllById($id);
        if (sizeof($data) != 0 )
        {
            foreach ($data as $child)
            {   
                $array[]    = $child;
                // How do i rerun the loop until no more downline ids are found without writing a bunch of foreach loops?
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I write a recursive function to get all the related downline ids?

Comment: your function requries 2 parameters. You only provide 1. if $data does not become a non empty array, the function won't return anything. And in your  foreach loop you only return for the first element in $data

Comment: Edited the invoke function. Still returns nothing, am i not doing the traversing correctly?

Comment: Reread previous comment: you are exiting the `for` loop on first entry. What about the other iterations? And what if there is no child? Then you don't return anything? Which means the recursive caller will also return nothing, ...etc

Comment: Is this not a scope issue. `$lineModel` does not exist in that function!  Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: `$this->downline` Nothing in the code makes me think this is a class/object so `$this` may be a mistake

Comment: @trincot How can i loop each record that is not empty before returning them in the recursive function?

Comment: I would answer if I would know the context of your code. It makes no sense that you first call the function with `downline` and then within that function as  `$this->downline`. How could that even work? What is `$lineModel`?

Comment: @trincot edited the question and removed my function for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your function returns something -- after the loop has completed (not during -- as you had in the first version of your question).

Although you pass an `$array` with the idea to fill it, you would need to ensure that the array is passed by reference, for which you must use the [`&` syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), otherwise the caller will not see the changes.

However, I find it cleaner to not specify that parameter at all (and using PHP's `&` syntax is not recommended -- it has strange side-effects). Instead, let the function *return* the array. The code that recursively calls this function, should then take that returned array and merge it with what it is collecting itself:

```
public function downline($id) {
    $lineModel = CLONEAPI::getModel('line');
    $data = $lineModel->getAllById($id);
    $array = [];
    foreach ($data as $child) {
        $array[] = $child['downline_id'];
        $array = array_merge($array, downline($child['downline_id']);
    }
    return $array;
}

$result = downline($someParentId);
```

Comment: Corrected my answer, as it did not actually collect the current child.

Answer (score 0):

@trincot

Your method works! I although I made a small edit to it to pass the array with existing data to the next recursive call.

```
public function downline($id) {
    $lineModel = CLONEAPI::getModel('line');
    $data = $lineModel->getAllById($id);
    $array = [];
    foreach ($data as $child) {
     $temp[] = $child['downline_id'];
     $array = array_merge($array, $temp, downline($child['downline_id']);
    }
    return $array;
}

$result = downline($someParentId);
```

After that, I got some duplicate ids from which I used array_unique to remove the duplicate values.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Indeed, the child itself should of course be added to the output array.